# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='',port=443) Max retries exceeded in apache and upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header in nginx

Tags: python, apache, nginx, flask, python-requests

I am trying to fetch a government URL https://ahara.kar.nic.in/status2/, but I am getting errors like **'Max retries exceeded with timed out'** in Apache server and **upstream prematurely closed connection while reading the response header** error in the nginx server I tried all the answers available in web for more than a week but no luck, so I am posting this question, I feel this may help me to find the solution

It may not be a timeout issue or upstream connection issue because the same URL is working fine in GoDaddy's shared server at https://mycard.easycardmaker.com/status-page but the same code is not working in Hostinger's Ubuntu VPS

I tried first with flask/ nginx/ wsgi, got this issue, so I thought It may be nginx config issue then I reinstalled plain OS and tried with Apache server

The issue I am getting in Hostinger's Ubuntu VPS is only for Government websites as I observed not for any others ex: https://itunes.apple.com/in/genre/ios-business/id6000?mt=8

Thanks, Your help will be most appreciated :)

I followed these below pages for configuring flask app in Ubuntu VPS

1. For NGINX: https://www.codewithharry.com/blogpost/flask-app-deploy-using-gunicorn-nginx/
2. For Apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

   ```
   from flask import Flask 
   import requests
   from time import sleep

   app = Flask(__name__) 

   @app.route("/") 
   def hello():
      try:

          headers = {
            "Host": "ahara.kar.nic.in",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }
        sleep(5)
        res = requests.get("https://ahara.kar.nic.in/status2/", verify=False, headers=headers, timeout=30)
        print(res.text)
        return "Hello, Got response"

       except requests.ConnectionError as e:
          print(e)
          return 'Failed to establish a connection'


    if __name__ == "__main__": 
     app.run()
   ```

**easyCardMakerApp.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName 195.35.7.181
ServerAdmin admin@easycardmaker.online
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/easyCardMaker/easyCardMaker.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/easyCardMaker>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>

 Alias /static /var/www/easyCardMaker/static

<Directory /var/www/easyCardMaker/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**easyCardMaker.wsgi**

```
import sys 
import logging 
from app import app as application

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr) 
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/easyCardMaker/")  

application.secret_key = '28fc4673473543eda2e6a9f503f4bb71'
```

Comment: Apache / Nginx doesn't really have anything to do with those errors. It's your Python code that is getting those errors when making the requests. If that code works in one environment but not another you should begin by checking the differences between the two environment's network. To begin, in the environment where the code doesn't work is there a firewall to block requests? Is it configured properly to let your requests go through? Is it possible that the server you are making requests to is blocking requests from your environment?

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat, Thanks for the response, my server firewall status is already Inactive, Any other suggestion to check this firewall issue if this is the case?

Comment: Oh wait are you getting this error in Apache of Nginx when calling your Python application? Please share necessary configuration / debugging information then. Your Python code alone won't be enough.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Added Apache configurations, please check